# R data.table count rows until value is reached

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to return a new column in a data.table which shows how many rows down until a value lower than the current value (of Temp) is reached.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table( Temp = runif(10,0,20) )
```

This is how I would like it to look:

```
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(
        Temp = runif(10,0,20),
        Day_Below_Temp = c("5","1","3","2","1","NA","3","1","1","NA")
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the newly implemented non-equi joins in the current development version, this can be accomplished in a straightforward manner as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
DT[, row := .I] # add row numbers
DT[DT, x.row-i.row, on = .(row > row, Temp < Temp), mult="first"]
# [1]  5  1  3  2  1 NA  3  1  1 NA
```

The row number is necessary since we need to find indices lower than the current index, hence needs to be a condition in the join. We perform a *self-join*, i.e., for each row in `DT` (inner), based on condition provided to `on` argument, we find the first matching row index in `DT` (outer). Then we subtract the row indices to get the position from the current row. `x.row` refers to the index of outer `DT` and `i.row` to the inner `DT`.

To get the devel version, see installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

---

On 1e5 rows:

```
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(Temp = runif(1e5L, 0L, 20L))

DT[, row := .I]
system.time({
    ans = DT[DT, x.row-i.row, on = .(row > row, Temp < Temp), mult="first", verbose=TRUE]
})
# Non-equi join operators detected ... 
#   forder took ... 0.001 secs
#   Generating non-equi group ids ... done in 0.452 secs
#   Recomputing forder with non-equi ids ... done in 0.001 secs
#   Found 623 non-equi group(s) ...
# Starting bmerge ...done in 8.118 secs
# Detected that j uses these columns: x.row,i.row 
#    user  system elapsed 
#   8.492   0.038   8.577 

head(ans)
# [1]  5  1  3  2  1 12
tail(ans)
# [1]  2  1  1  2  1 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame( Temp = runif(10,0,20) )
dt %>% mutate(Day_Below_Temp = 
                 sapply(1:length(Temp), function(x) min(which(.$Temp[x:length(.$Temp)] < .$Temp[x]))-1))

        Temp Day_Below_Temp
1   5.751550              5
2  15.766103              1
3   8.179538              3
4  17.660348              2
5  18.809346              1
6   0.911130            Inf
7  10.562110              3
8  17.848381              1
9  11.028700              1
10  9.132295            Inf
```

Comment: Ok that's great @jeremycg, and to make sure I understand it right if I wanted to check what row the Temp value went lower than an alternative column (additional column) value how would this method change? Thank you

Comment: No problem. You would change the `.$Temp[x:length(.$Temp)]` to `.$additionalcolumn[x:length(.$Temp)]`.

Comment: Unfortunately this (and my own deleted answer) seem to be as slow as a wet week. Even on 100K cases, this is taking a minute plus. I think there has to be a way to get around this through some joins or something tricky. Arun, where are you?!

Comment: @thelatemail I got `sapply(1:length(dt$Temp), function(x) Position(function(z){z<dt$Temp[x]}, dt$Temp[x:length(dt$Temp)])-1)` using Find/Position, but it is much slower :(

Comment: @jeremycg - dang, I'm holding out that Arun can fix the problems :-). By the way, who downvoted you? Seems a bit harsh!

Comment: I wonder what's the `dplyr` role here? The `mutate`? Can't this be achieved with just `$`?

Comment: :) no worries, I'll live

Comment: @thelatemail, lol.. just seeing this comment. I couldn't think of anything faster than (the newly implemented) non-equi joins at the moment.. takes ~8.5s on 100K rows..

Answer (score 1):

This does the job - not very fast though

```
DT[, rowN := .I]

DT[, Day_Below_Temp := which(DT$Temp[rowN:nrow(DT)] < Temp)[1] - 1, 
   by = rowN
   ][, rowN := NULL]
```